# javafx how to make a panel public static

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

while i am trying to make a panel  public static it don't show any error in compiling but during run time it gives an error like:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at schoolmanagement2.SchoolManagement2.start(SchoolManagement2.java:32)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    ... 1 more
```

I want to know why this error is coming as output

Help me please...

and is it possible to make a panel public static or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code depicting your error. Most probably the FXML path is incorrect.

Comment: it means it is possible to make a panel public static

Comment: If you can provide more light on the requirement, may be we can help.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: i want to get the size of previous panel and use that size for next panels. as clients are able to  change the size of panels.

Comment: None of that has anything at all to do with being static, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was possible in JFX 2. In JFX 8 they took out this functionality.

You can't do it.

You can make another variable that is static that is equal to this non-static pane. This is possible. But you will need to manually set your new static variable to be equal to your non-static variable during the start or initialize method.
Better yet, create a static reference to this instance of the class in your class. As such:

```
private static Controller instance;
```

And initialize it during your, once again, start or initialize methods. Then you can reference it with:

```
Controller.instance.panel.doSomething();
```

Comment: how could i do with jfx8

Comment: Like I said, it's impossible. Try the workarounds I mentioned?